# returning promise from factory method after combining multiple API calls and processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have been using the promise returned by simple http method from a long while. But I have a need where I need to first chain multiple API call and process the data and return that data. Problem what I am facing with current implementation is the factory is not returning the promise and hence not waiting for data and executes next line of the controller.

```
app.factory('mytestService', ['$http', function($http){
    getSomeDataById: function(id){
    var userAllProjects = [];
     var myHelperService = this.getSecondData;
     this.getFirstData(id).then(function(response){ // first api call
         var idObjectValue = response['result'][0]['id'];
         myHelperService(idObjectValue).then(function(response){ //second api call
           userAllProjects= response['projectList']
        });
   });
    return userAllProjects
   }
]);
```

Now in controller when I do:

```
$scope.allProjects = mytestService.getSomeDataById(1234);
console.log($scope.allProjects);
```

the console prints undefined. I know this is because, it doesn't wait for the service to complete and exscutes the next line.

I am little novice to angular promises, so no idea how to handle that. Can anyone please help me here.
 Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: the function `getSomeDataById` returns nothing

Comment: It returns userAllProjects after all the processings.

Comment: It does not wait for the request to be finished

Comment: You should do the `then` inside your controller

Comment: Can not I do above method (in factory) inside service? Because I need to use this at multiple places.

Comment: You wont know when the request is finished then

Comment: How is your `getSomeDataById` function getting called? and where?

Comment: getSomeDataById is called from controller $scope.allProjects = mytestService.getSomeDataById(1234);

Comment: @Weedoze any suggestion how to make this work if I need to use that at multiple places?

Comment: @JK_Jha use `then` inside your controller

Comment: @Weedoze I tried that. But I get error .then is not a function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
getSomeDataById: function(id){
  var userAllProjects = $q.defer();
  var myHelperService = this.getSecondData;
  this.getFirstData(id).then(function(response){ // first api call
     var idObjectValue = response['result'][0]['id'];
     myHelperService(idObjectValue).then(function(response){ //second api call
       userAllProjects.resolve(response['projectList'])
    });
  });
  return userAllProjects.promise;
}
```

The idea is, you create a deferred object first, and return the promise. When data is available you resolve the deferred object and the data will be made available in your controller.

Note: you will need to add dependency on `$q`

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. You saved my day @Vivek. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Introducing `Promise Chaining`, it is generally preferred over creating new `deferred`

```
getSomeDataById: function(id){
    var userAllProjects = [];
    var myHelperService = this.getSecondData;

    // returning promise rather than creating a new one, 
    // to prevent unresolved promise if one of the calls in the chain gets rejected
    return this.getFirstData(id).then(function(response){ // first api call
        var idObjectValue = response['result'][0]['id'];
        return myHelperService(idObjectValue);  //second api call
        // instead of writing .then here, 
        // it can be moved to the outer layer for easy reading

    }).then(function(response){
        userAllProjects = response['projectList'];
        // return something you need to use in .then of getSomeDataById() here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then` inside your controller instead

**Factory**

```
app.factory('mytestService', ['$http', function($http) {
    getSomeDataById: function(id) {
        var myHelperService = this.getSecondData;
        return this.getFirstData(id);
    },
    secondApiCall : function(idObjectValue){
      return myHelperService(idObjectValue);
    }
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
mytestService.getSomeDataById(1234).then(function(response){
  mytestService.secondApiCall(response['result'][0]['id']).then(function(response2){
    $scope.allProjects = response.data;
  })
});
```